# Choosing a suitable GLM family for zero-inflated data non-integer data

Tags: generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution

I am currently aiming to find any statistical difference between site fidelity for four shark species between sex and sample site. This uses a mark-recapture method and thus the data is heavily zero inflated for sharks that were not recaptured. Since the values for site fidelity are not integers I am unable to fit a zero-inflated Poisson model using the "pscl" package. Are there any other options in terms of GLM model families that I could use, or are there other statistical tests that I could potentially use to find any differences between the groups?

Comment: you could check out a zero inflated or hurdle model with a different nonzero likelihood, like say the lognormal likelihood, using the "hurdlr" R packag's hurdle function.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I think the hurdlr package only works with count data. My data contains decimals as they are proportion values and thus can't be used. If I have missed something please let me know.

Comment: lognormal likelihood

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/glmmTMB.pdf zero-inflated gamma `ziGamma`?

Comment: I have looked into the distribution using a histogram and a Tweedie distribution appears to be the best fit for my data. Therefore I have decided to use that